# Batch Login(won't used already stored user and pass)

Tags: windows, batch-file, authentication

So i'm working a batch login file and I can register and login fine all in the same session. When I close the file and re-open the login file I can't use the previous login information, so I have to make a new user and pass.

```
 @echo off
 color 1f
 title Login

 :Home
 cls
 echo Welcome to the Master Batch Program!
 echo 1) Register
 echo 2) Login
 echo 3) Info
 echo 4) Exit
 choice /C:1234 /m Choice?

 if ERRORLEVEL 4 (
 goto :End
 )

 if ERRORLEVEL 3 (
 goto :Info
 )

 if ERRORLEVEL 2 (
 goto :Login
 )

 if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 goto :Register
 )

 :Login
 echo.
 cls
 echo.
 echo.
 echo.
 echo.
 echo.
 echo ============================
 echo [       LOGIN PANEL        ]
 echo ============================
 echo.
 set /p "userm=Username:"
 set /p "passm=Password:"
 echo.
 if exist "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Batch\account\%userl%.user" goto success
if exist "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Batch\account\%passl%.pass" goto success
if not exist "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Batch\account\%userl%.user" goto failed
if not exist "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Batch\account\%passl%.pass" goto failed
goto failed

:success
cls
echo You have successfully logged in!
pause
start C:\Users\user\Desktop\Batch\src\main.bat
exit

:failed
cls
echo Incorrect username and password.
pause
goto Home

:Register
echo.
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ====================================
echo [         REGISTER PANEL           ]
echo ====================================
echo.
set /p "userl=Username:"
set /p "passl=Password:"
echo %userl% >> C:\Users\user\Desktop\Batch\account\%userl%.user
echo %passl% >> C:\Users\user\Desktop\Batch\account\%passl%.pass
goto success2

:success2
cls
echo Your Account Is Now Created!
pause
goto Home

:End
echo.
echo Bye, bye!
echo.

pause

cls
```

The Info option is not included in the code above because that works fine.
Like I said the login info created is only good for that session and when I close the "main.bat" file and open the "login.bat" file again i have to create a new password and username. So in a sense, I need help making the "login.bat" program to use the username and password that were created already.

Comment: something does not make sense here with the setting of the variables userl and passl.. let me just scan through this again.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I figured it out. Instead of creating two files for "user" and "pass" i saved both of them into a .cmd and then used "call" to call the .cmd so i can use an already created account.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two files for "user" and "pass" i saved both of them into a .cmd and then used "call" to call the .cmd so i can use an already created account

`@echo SET USERNAME=%user% >> C:\Users\ItZzVast\Desktop\BatchLogin\LoginInfo.cmd
@echo SET PASSWORD=%pass% >> C:\Users\ItZzVast\Desktop\BatchLogin\LoginInfo.cmd`

Then in the login page of the batch file i used:
`call C:\Users\ItZzVast\Desktop\BatchLogin\LoginInfo.cmd`
Then have the person type in their info and verifying if there is a "LoginInfo.cmd" with that information in it with "if exist" and "if not exist"